# Use find in Terminal to remove directories and files of same search parameter

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line, search

If I type the following into Terminal, it will remove all files that meet the search parameter:

```
sudo find . -type f -name "*Xilisoft*" -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

Then if I start again and type it with `d` instead of `f` it will remove all the directories

```
sudo find . -type d -name "*Xilisoft*" -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

How do I get it to remove type `f` and `d` in one fell swoop?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can provide multiple `-type` options with `-o`, such as `-type f -o -type d` in a single command.

```
find . -name "*Xilisoft*" -type f -o -name "*Xilisoft*" -type d
```

<sup>`-o` matches all parameters, so the `-name` is provided twice in the above command.

Note that find can delete the results using `-delete` rather than `-exec rm -rf {}`.</sup>

Comment: I didn't know about the `-delete` option so this comes as a welcome piece of information.